# using setcontentview twice

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, paint, bar-chart

I want to implement chart like structure.

For bar graph I'm using no. of buttons **in my main activity** and hence the output is as following :

[image: screenshot]

---

Then I'm creating new class which extends `View` in order to draw x and y axes for graph using canvas as following:

```
public class Draw extends View {

Paint paint = new Paint();

public Draw(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  }

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawLine(20, 50, 20, 200, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(20, 200, 200, 200, paint);
  }
}
```

But the problem is, after I use following lines of code in my main activity:

```
Draw draw = new Draw(this);
setContentView(draw);
```

I get following output as I'm setting the `ContentView` again:

[image: screenshot]

---

So my question is how do I integrate both these views in order to get below output:

[image: screenshot]

Is there any other way for doing the same?
ANY HELP APPRECIATED.

### EDIT

Based on various suggestions, I removed

```
Draw draw = new Draw(this);
setContentView(draw);
```

from my activity class and instead put these lines in main xml layout.

```
<com.example.calci.Draw 
    android:id="@+id/draw" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

But I'm getting following **EXCEPTION**:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calci/com.example.calci.CalciActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #468: Error inflating class com.example.calci.Draw

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Draw(Context,AttributeSet)
at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:643)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:472)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:480)
```

### EDIT 2

By adding `AttributeSet attributeSet` to constructor, I got the desired result.

But can anyone suggest whether I should use buttons or rectangles from canvas to draw bar graph.

Please note that I need to modify the height of the bar graphs dynamically based on `seekbar` value.

Comment: Why dont you draw two lines on left and bottom of the graph.

Comment: not possible in view class. I've used it in activity class twice...

Comment: Please chech EDIT 2 in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using xml for bar graph layout, you can include there your new created view like this:

```
<view
    class="your.package.name.ProjectName$NameOfYourClass" 
    id="@+id/draw"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

More about using custom components: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: @GAMA Try adding method to your view class:
public Draw(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super.Draw(context, attributeSet);
}

Comment: Please chech EDIT 2 in question.

Comment: @GAMA Seems like it's easier for you to use buttons as you wouldn't have to redraw canvas, but using rectangles is more professional. If you want to draw rectangles, try using invalidate() method on your view.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you can include your `Draw` view in the same layout as your bar graph layout, perhaps in a `FrameLayout` and avoid setting the content view twice.

However, use of buttons for a charting application seems more like a hack. You can think of drawing the bar graphs also on the `Canvas` like the way you are drawing the axes.

Comment: Please chech EDIT 2 in question.

Comment: I will recommend using Canvas for drawing the bar graphs as you would have finer control over the position of the bars. Please keep in mind that it is difficult to position buttons on exact coordinates when the application runs on devices with different resolutions.